# Xcode how to view assembly with virtual memory locations of code

Tags: xcode, debugging, assembly

I'm not even sure if I'm phrasing my question correctly, but the reason why I'm asking is because I was recently reading a [Mike Ash blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/tales-from-the-crash-mines-issue-1.html)

If you scroll halfway down to **"Examining Frame 1"**, he says "Let's look at the actual assembly code for..." then pastes some assembly code:

```
    0x103fbf0ba -[EXNetConnection execute:timeout:completionBlock:] proc near
    0x103fbf0ba var_20          = qword ptr -20h
    0x103fbf0ba    push    rbp
    0x103fbf0bb    mov     rbp, rsp
    0x103fbf0be    push    r15
    0x103fbf0c0    push    r14
    0x103fbf0c2    push    rbx
    0x103fbf0c3    push    rax
    0x103fbf0c4    mov     r14, rcx
    0x103fbf0c7    movsd   [rbp+var_20], xmm0
    0x103fbf0cc    mov     r15, rdi
    0x103fbf0cf    mov     rdi, rdx
    0x103fbf0d2    call    cs:_objc_retain_ptr
    0x103fbf0d8    mov     rbx, rax
    0x103fbf0db    mov     rsi, cs:selRef_execute_timeout_completionBlock_updateCallback_
    0x103fbf0e2    mov     rdi, r15
```

but his paste includes the memory addresses for what I can only assume is the location at which the instruction lives in memory? (Somebody please validate/invalidate this hypothesis for me)

I figured out how to view assembly code (Assistant editor, click manual->assembly) But I can't figure out how to view the locations in memory at runtime.

Does anybody know how Mike was able to do this?

Comment: Nevermind, literally right after I posted this question I tried clicking on "disassembly" and found what I was looking for.  A subsequent google: "disassembly vs assembly" is all that I needed

Comment: It actually looks like that particular disassembly was produced by IDA, a standalone disassembler and reverse engineering tool.

Comment: Interesting.  Why do you say that?

Comment: The `proc near` and `var_20` are things that I wouldn't expect to see in a IDE's debugger's disassembly output. They do appear in the disassembly created by IDA. Also from the article: "our usual approach at Plausible Labs is to load up the binary in a disassembler"

Comment: Oh, and "In future issues, we'll address some of the tools we used in this analysis, including Hopper and IDA Pro."

Comment: Ah I see.  I haven't even finished reading the entire blog through, and plan on re-reading it at least once.  This guy writes about really cool stuff.  Do you know if I would need to use a disassembler to debug into Apple's code, then?  I'm occasionally crashing on a `[super setDocument:]` call but I can't follow Mike's steps to debug it because I can't seem to see anything beyond my code

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Xcode or ObjectiveC(?) so I don't know how good it would be at debugging a problem like that. Though I would expect most people manage to debug their programs without using something like IDA, even when the crash occurs outside their own code.